# JavaScript Math assistance needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am programming a calculator, and I have come across a problem.  The programming and the mathematics that the programming is based on do not match up.  I'll provide the code below.

```
    function calculate() {

  console.log(1);
  var activity = $("#txtActivity").val();

  var days = parseInt( $("#txtDays").val(), 10);
  var hours = parseInt( $("#txtHours").val(), 10);
  var minutes = parseInt( $("txtMinutes").val(), 10);
  var seconds = parseInt( $("txtSeconds").val(), 10);

  var MoneyMadeDuringActivity = (days * 21464) + (hours * 2683) + (minutes * 4472) + (seconds * 0.74);



  $("#CalcOutput").html("In the time it takes me to " + activity + ",<br />Barack Obama makes $" + MoneyMadeDuringActivity);

}

  $("#btnCalculate").click(function() {
    calculate();
  });
```

The consists of 4 html textboxes which each require integer input.  The code produces the following output:

**In the time it takes me to Enter something here, Barack Obama makes $MoneyMadeDuringActivity **

I tested this code by simply entering 1 in each textbox.  It should be $24,192.46, but instead I'm getting $28,619.74.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help!

Comment: I don't know where you're getting that it should be 24192.46 but 21464 + 2683 +4472 + .74 is 28619.74

Comment: Start by breaking down the problem into smaller components. Output the MoneyMadeDuringActivity days, then hours, then minutes, then seconds. Verify your calculations on each one to determine which area the problem is in. Rinse and repeat until you find the specific problem, then update your post with an [edit] if you're still stuck. :)

Comment: `$("#txtHours")` vs `$("txtMinutes")`?

Comment: the incorrect jQuery selectors like `$("txtSeconds").val()` were just pointed out in same code you posted a few minutes ago in another question. Likely best to fix obvious things before posting a new question

Comment: I would try using the jquery basic arithmetic plugin because jquery plugins always solve my problems and jquery is great and does all things and is good too as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a decimal point in the `minutes` multiplier. It looks like it should be `44.72`, not `4472`.